# Fulfilling strange requirements with CSS (kind of simulating frames)

Tags: html, css, layout, scroll

I'm struggling to find a way to code a site according to our strange requirements. The site should be displayed correctly in all browsers from IE6 to Opera.

The website is structured in three parts. It contains a header at the top, a navigation on the left an the rest of the screen should be filled with the content section. The following picture should help you better understand my description.

[layout of the website http://www.4freeimagehost.com/uploads/820aee2ded8b.png](http://www.4freeimagehost.com/uploads/820aee2ded8b.png)

Here comes the kicker: Each of the three sections should be scrollable separately and no browser scrollbar should appear. The page should be displayed similar as if it would use frames. Of course, on a big enough screen, no scroll bars should appear.

It doesn't matter which way is used to display the site, although frames aren't an option an divs would be preferred.
There are two conditions:

- The site should always fill the whole browser screen. The header and the content section should reach to the right border of the page, and the navigation as well as the content to the bottom.
- As soon as the site is    scaled down -- whether due to resizing the browser window or due to a smaller resolution -- a scrollbar for every single section should appear, but no "browser scrollbar" for the whole page. The header should always retain it's height and the navigation always it's width.

Do you know a way how all this can be achieved?

Yours
Bernhard

edit 1: Oh, and I forgot: The site should be passable viewable in 1024x768.
edit 2: Another thing: The header has got a fixed height and the navigation a fixed width. The height of the navigation as well as the height and width of the content should fill  the entire screen.

Comment: Tell your customer that people don't build such things. It's unprofessional.

Comment: Use frames.

While they do have drawbacks, they are quick, simple and work in IE6.

Comment: This site may help point you in a decent direction, but you'll definitely need to play with the CSS overflow a bit: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-2-column-left-menu.htm

Comment: I know that this is not the best requirement out there and I ain't allowed to use frames.
See my answer below for more details.

Comment: @David Dorward: pls stop coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED:**

i have found this article

> - http://www.alistapart.com/articles/conflictingabsolutepositions/

just CSS & HTML i think is what you are looking for!

**FINAL DEMO**: http://jsbin.com/icemo3/24

In responce to your last comment, i have worked out this solution that require also a bit of jquery (javascript) please see the demo and use the demo code!

```
$(window).load(function() {
getWindowProportion()
});

$(window).resize(function() {
getWindowProportion()
});

function getWindowProportion() {
 $('#wrapper').attr('style', 'width:' + $(window).width() + 'px');
    $('#header').attr('style', 'height:200px;width:' + $(window).width() + 'px');
    $('#navigation').attr('style', 'height:' + ($(window).height() - 200) + 'px;top:200px;width:300px');
    $('#content').attr('style', 'width:' + ($(window).width() - 300) + 'px;top:200px;height:' + ($(window).height() - 200) + 'px;left:' + ($('#navigation').width()) + 'px');
};
```

---

**CSS** DEMO 2: http://jsbin.com/icemo3/2

**CSS** DEMO 3: http://jsbin.com/icemo3/3

```
* { margin:0; padding:0 }
html, body { margin:0; padding:0;  position:relative; overflow:auto; width:100%;  height:100%; }
#content { float:left; width:  80%; background: cyan; height:80%;  top:20%; left:20% }
#navigation { float:left; width:  20%; background: green; height:80%;  top:20% }
#header {  width:  100%; background: red; height:20%; }
.scrollme { margin:0; padding:0; overflow: auto;  position:absolute; }
p { margin:10px }

<div id="header" class="scrollme"><p>some text here</p></div>
<div id="navigation" class="scrollme"><p>some text here</p></div>
<div id="content" class="scrollme"><p>some text here</p></div>
```

**NOTE:**

```
tested on: 
IE6+
Chrome
Firefox
Opera
```

1. each section have its own scroll-bar!
2. each section have 100% width and height!
3. no browser window scroll-bar appear!
4. each section always retain its proportion
5. work on all screen resolution

Comment: This doesn't meet the requirement "always fill the whole browser screen" or the requirement "to the bottom" or the requirement "no 'browser scrollbar' for the whole page"

Comment: quote: "The site should always fill the whole browser screen"

Comment: I've tried it, but I'm experiencing the same problem as I've written in my new answer. The page stretches out over the browser window. Or maybe I've done something wrong ...

Comment: Thank you for your effort, aSeptik.
My header section has a fixed height in px and my navigation a fixed with. As soon as I apply these settings to your example, change the position of the sections so that there is no empty space and then change the height of the content section to 100%, the page again stretches until outside the browser screen. See my second edit of the question.

Comment: Thank you for your help, aSeptik, but it may take a little time, until I can test your new version. I'll write you when I've done so.

Answer (score 0):

Nice question.  For this one, you have to find the browser screen resolution size of x and y (maybe using javascript).  with this size, assign the width and height in the div section.

In div, you can use like this way

```
<div id="nameID" style="position: relative; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: auto;"></div>
```

Try this method. I think you can get a correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

So, I now found a way to make this work without the header.

The navigation section uses the following CSS:

```
float: left;
height: 100%
overflow: auto;
width:185px;
```

The content section uses this:

```
height: 400px;
overflow: auto;
```

As well as

```
html, body{
    height: 100%
}
```

The only problem is that when I insert the header, the site stretches until outside of the browser window. This is due to the use of `height: 100%`.
Do you know how I can make the page still fit the into the browser screen?

edit 1:
The following JavaScript would do the trick, at least in Firefox:

```
window.onresize = resize;

function resize(){
    heightWithoutHeader = (window.innerHeight - 85) + "px"; 
    document.getElementById("content").style.height = heightWithoutHeader;
    document.getElementById("navigation").style.height = heightWithoutHeader;
}
```

But maybe there's a more elegant CSS solution ...

Answer (score 0):

Frames still exist for a reason. There's a time and a place. This is probably it.

But here's a way to do it with CSS instead of frames, anyway:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Not Frames</title>
        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
            .fake-content {
                margin: 20px;
                background-color: #000;
                height: 1500px;
                width: 1500px;
            }

            /* Get rid of the original scrollbars */
            html, body
            {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;

                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;

                overflow: hidden;
            }

            /* The frames */
            .frame
            {
                position: absolute;
                overflow: scroll;
            }

            /* The sections */
            #header
            {
                top: 0;
                height: 250px;
                width: 100%;

                background-color: #F00;
            }

            #sidebar
            {
                top: 250px;
                bottom: 0;
                left: 0;
                width: 250px;

                background-color: #0F0;
            }

            #content
            {
                top: 250px;
                bottom: 0;
                left: 250px;
                right: 0;

                background-color: #00F;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header" class="frame">
            <div class="fake-content">Content</div>
        </div>
        <div id="sidebar" class="frame">
            <div class="fake-content">Content</div>
        </div>
        <div id="content" class="frame">
            <div class="fake-content">Content</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: IE6 doesn't support setting opposite edges with absolute positioning (e.g. `top: 250px; bottom: 0`) so this won't work.

Comment: A work-around for IE6 involves setting one edge's position as normal, then assigning a dynamic width via one of IE's proprietary css expressions. Check the bottom of this article for a full explanation: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/conflictingabsolutepositions/

Comment: Okay, I think I have another way of doing it with ought to work with IE6. Coming up shortly... Edit: Or not. Now I think about it some more it won't. D'oh!